# Proxy HTTP POST form data in Mule 3.1.2

Tags: http, mule

I need to send some post data to another server in mule 3.1.2. Here is my mule-config file：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
xmlns:rmi="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rmi" xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.1/mule-http.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.1/mule-scripting.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rmi http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rmi/3.1/mule-rmi.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/3.1/mule-stdio.xsd
      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.1/mule-vm.xsd">

    <flow name="cxfFlow">
        <!-- Accept a http request from the specific address -->
        <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:5678/httpHello">
            <byte-array-to-string-transformer/>
            <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>

        <!-- This component is just set to show the message accecpted from the request -->
        <scripting:component>
            <scripting:script engine="groovy">
                def msg = "message: $message;\npayload:$payload;\n result:$result".toString()
                println msg
                println "init param:$payload"
                return payload
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>

        <!-- This component is set to parse the parameter passed by the request -->
        <scripting:component>
            <scripting:script engine="groovy">
                    def paramstr = ""
                    for( param in payload){
                        paramstr = paramstr + "&amp;" + param.key+ "=" + param.value
                    }
                println "querystr:$paramstr"
                return paramstr.substring(1)
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>

        <choice>
            <when expression="payload.size()>0" evaluator="groovy">
                <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/webproj/index.jsp" method="POST" contentType="text/http">
                </http:outbound-endpoint>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <scripting:component>
                    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
                        println payload
                        return "no parameter is given!"
                    </scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I make a post request to http://localhost:5678/httpHello , and send some parameters. In the http://localhost:8080/webproj/index.jsp page, I examine the parameter I received, but the parameter is empty. I want to receive parameters sent in the beginning in the index.jsp page, how to change my mule-config file? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the inbound and outbound HTTP content-types are **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, here is a configuration that does what you want (ie. logging the payload and choosing a different response based on the presence of parameters):

```
<flow name="webFormFlow">
    <!-- Accept a http request from the specific address -->
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:5678/httpHello">
        <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- This logger is just set to show the message accepted from the request -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" />

    <choice>
        <when expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" evaluator="groovy">
            <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/webproj/index.jsp"
                method="POST" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <message-properties-transformer>
                <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/plain" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <expression-transformer>
                <return-argument expression="no parameter is given!"
                    evaluator="string" />
            </expression-transformer>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: what if I want to send parameter via POST method, not querystring? I don't want the parameter appear in the url.

Comment: That would be easier then: remove #[header:queryString] from the outbound URI and remove the whole scripting component that builds paramstr. Mule will POST the map payload as the entity to your JSP.

Comment: how could I get the payload? I checked the parameter map, it's empty.

Comment: Hold on, how do you "a post request to http://localhost:5678/httpHello , and send some parameters"? How do you POST these parameters? Which content-type?

Comment: I submit parameters to localhost:5678/httpHello from a form, so it should be text/html. I didn't change the content-type from then on.

Comment: Nah, the encoding is either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data. See the RFC: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4. If you haven't specified any, then it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Let me review my response now that you've given this important precision.

Comment: sorry, I took it for granted. I'm new to mule, and all I want to do is receive parameters from a http inbound-endpoint and pass them to another http outbound-endpoint.